# Sheaf of a complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, sheaf-theory

Let 
$$ F(U) = \left\{ \mbox{ all complex analytic functions } f \mbox{ on } U \mid z \frac{df}{dz}=1 \right\}$$
for any domain $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

I want to show that:

1. $F$ is a sheaf.
2. The stalk of $F$ at $0$ is empty.
3. The stalk at any other point is non-canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

I know that the presheaf of continuous function is a sheaf (as they have the gluing property over open coverings), so also analytic functions (which are $C^\infty$) are sheaf. However, there are two problems is: a function that satisfy $d \frac{df}{dz}=1$ actually is $$\frac{df}{dz} = \frac{1}{z}$$ which is not analytic in 0. Moreover, is not the differential equation $\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{1}{z}$ is unique up to a constant - the family of solution is $f(z) = \ln(z) + c$ with $c \in \mathbb{C}$? Then it follows that $F$ is a sheaf with stalk $$\{f(z) = \ln(z) + c \mid c \in \mathbb{C} \} \cong \mathbb{C}$$
and empty stalk at 0 since there is no analytic function such that $0 \cdot \frac{df}{dt} = 1$. Are my consideration here are correct?

**Added in edit:**

We can define $\ln(z)$ as the extension of 
$$ \ln(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n $$
to the complex number. Of course one needs to check where it converges and well-defined, and then arise the issue of branch cuts. I am no expert on complex analysis but my intuition says that $\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{1}{z}$ has a family of solutions differ by constants. Is this correct?

Comment: First, you have a typo in the definition of $F(U)$. Second, what does $\ln(z)$ mean?

Comment: There is a differential equation $f'(z)=1/z$. If we extending from the reals its solution is $\ln(z) + c$ but if this incorrect denoted by $g(z)$ it solution such that $(g(z)+c)' = 1/z$.

Comment: Yes, but when you work in $\Bbb C$, you have to be very careful with the meaning of $\ln$. It won't necessarily be defined on every open subset $U\subset\Bbb C-\{0\}$!

Comment: You are right. But if we define $f(z)$ via a Laurent expansion then it have a solution $g(z)$ and every $g(z)+c$ is also a solution. What it is important that $g(z)$ is unique up to $c$.

Comment: No, it's not a matter of Laurent expansion at all. The function has no poles. But it has a *branch point* at $0$ and you are only guaranteed a section of this sheaf on $U\subset\Bbb C-\{0\}$ if $U$ is simply connected.

Comment: Please forgive me, I haven't touched complex analysis for years. This why I need help here. But as for the branch cut, when $\ln(z)$ is defined up to $2\pi i$, does not the constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$ address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of this exercise is to arrive at the concept of complex  logarithm from  the sheaf direction, not to fall back onto the   power series definition. I suggest *not* using notation $\ln$, or any prior knowledge of logarithms,  in your solution.

The stalk is empty over $0$ because $z=0$ makes it impossible for $zf'(z)=1$ to hold.

Next, fix a  point $z_0\ne 0$. Let $(f,\Omega )$ be a function element that satisfies $zf'=1$ in $\Omega$. (Here $\Omega$ is a   neighborhood of $z_0$ that does not include $0$). Then for every $c\in\mathbb C$ we also have 
$z(f+c)'=1$. In particular, we can ensure $f(z_0)=0$ by subtracting a constant from $f$. 
If $(g,\Omega)$ satisfies $zf'=1$, then $z(f-g)'=0$ which implies $g=f+c$. Thus, we have the isomorphism between the stalk at $z_0$ and $\mathbb C$, given by $g\mapsto g(z_0)$.  (They are isomorphic as fields... and I don't   understand the "non-canonical" part,  unless "canonical" refers to something that can be carried out globally?).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves 2 and 3. Now I need to use the definition to show $F$ is a sheaf, namely, the patching condition: if there are sections coincide on overlaps of open sets then there exists a global section.

Comment: @LinAlgMan Yes. You know  that analytic functions form a sheaf; so patches can be glued; and if the condition $zf'=1$ is satisfied on some open sets, it is satisfied on their union. It's hard to write something here that's not tautological.